# Cos'è "la storia del moscon d'oro"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Ma si vede lontano un miglio che sei innamorata cotta... E 
>   di chi, poi. È proprio vera **la storia del moscon d'oro**: te, sembrava chissà che pretese 
>   avessi, e ti sei contentata di quello scalzacane.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "la storia del moscon d'oro" in questo brano. Si tratta di un modo di dire? L'ho cercata nel Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli, ma non l'ho trovata. Mi potreste spiegare cosa significa?

Comment: Credo si tratti di un moscone che, dopo tanto volare, si posò sulla m-.

Comment: ***Il moscon d'oro***: https://it-it.facebook.com/THE105ZOO/posts/10151442163153722

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La storia del moscon d'oro è una favoletta morale che racconta di un moscone dorato, bellissimo e desiderato da tutti i fiori, che continuava a volare senza mai appoggiarsi su nessuno di essi. Alla fine, tratto in inganno, si appoggia per errore su di uno sterco, dove perde la sua lucentezza; dopo questo errore nessun fiore lo vuole più su di sé.

La morale della storia è adatta come monito per chi, superbo e altezzoso, rifiuta la compagnia degli altri, rischiando però di venire attratto da una cattiva compagnia che finisce per rovinarlo.

Non conosco esattamente l'origine della storia, che per la verità non viene citata frequentemente.

Comment: Ah, grazie! Adesso capisco il senso del brano!